# Disable Control+Alt+Delete without modifying GINA?

Tags: windows

How do I disable Ctrl+Alt+Delete sequence without modifying GINA or just blocking out Task manager?

Comment: Seriously. Please don't ship anything that does this.

Comment: True, this shouldn't be done in general, but there are applications where it matters.  I work on medical devices.  The user needs a full keyboard, but shouldn't be able to get behind the application.  In such a case we do need to disable CAD.  In our case we're using GINA, but that's going to have to change for Windows 7, haven’t figured that one out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/preventclose.aspx

This tells you how to hook the Ctrl+Alt+Del combination thus blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable Ctrl-Alt-Del, called the "Secure Attention Sequence".  This is by design of Microsoft for [security purposes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Login_spoofing).

Comment: Indeed. If you feel your application needs to override CAD, then either your design sucks, or you're building malware.

Comment: What about a program which limits users abilities which would be used at work?

Comment: If you're a system administrator, the correct way to do this is with Group Policy.

Comment: There's a reason for that. If you can't understand those reasons, then I would question whether you should be writing software for businesses at all.

Comment: If you were not able to disable Ctrl-Alt-Del, then THAT would be a security problem -- for example, think of a kiosk.  The security issue is that Windows won't allow a program to take over (to respond to) a Ctrl-Alt-Del.

Comment: @jdigital: There's a difference between allowing Ctrl+Alt+Del, and doing something with it. Under XP for example, let's say the key sequence is enabled, but all the buttons in the dialog that comes up are disabled. There's no security risk in that.

Comment: True, this shouldn't be done in general, but there are applications where it matters.  I work on medical devices.  The user needs a full keyboard, but shouldn't be able to get behind the application.  In such a case we do need to disable CAD. We do it with GINA.